# Solution for recurrence T(n)=t(n/2)+sqrt(n) using induction only

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, recursion, recurrence

I am looking to prove that T(n)=T(n/2)+sqrt(n) is O(sqrt(n)) given T(1)=1
using only induction.
It is easy to solve using the Master theorem but this is not the case.
I tried to assume

> T(n/2) < c*sqrt(n/2)

but didnt get very far with the rest of the proof.
Thank you all in advance for your answers.

Edit:
my line of solution (after the assumption above) is:

> T(n) <= c*sqrt(n/2)+sqrt(n) = sqrt(n)*(c/sqrt(2)+1) <= sqrt(n)*(c+1)

I dont know how to move from this to the required

> T(n)<=c*sqrt(n)

Comment: induction requires you to know the solution, which is given to you.  it's a non-constructive proof method. base case is clear .  *what you need to show is that the assertion is true for n if it is true for 1...n-1*.

Comment: Im trying to understand the difference between Big "T" and little "t" in your equation.

Comment: @trumpetlicks, I think it's a typo

Comment: @thang - thats what Im thinking :-)

Comment: ok hint #2: suppose T(n/2) is O(sqrt(n/2)) = O(sqrt(n)), show that T(n) is O(sqrt(n)).  Damn LaTeX doesn't work here.

Comment: hint #3: observe that if c sqrt(n) is O(sqrt(n)), then (c+1) sqrt(n) is also O(sqrt(n)).  No more.  I am gonna go get lunch now. :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, you're close.  So basically, as I mentioned in the comment, base case is simple.  For induction case, you want to show that T(n) is O(sqrt(n)) given that T(n/2) is O(sqrt(n/2)).

So, it goes like this:

```
T(n) = T(n/2) + sqrt(n)               ; this is just your recurrence
     < c sqrt(n/2) + sqrt(n)          ; since T(n/2) is O(sqrt(n))
                                      ; wlog here, assume c > 4
     = c sqrt(n) / sqrt(2) + sqrt(n)
     = (c/sqrt(2) + 1) sqrt(n)
```

observe that for c > 4,  c / sqrt(2) + 1 < c, so

```
(c/sqrt(2) + 1) sqrt(n) < c sqrt(n)
```

so

```
T(n) < c sqrt(n)
```

Therefore, T(n) is O(sqrt(n))

So there's a couple key points here that you missed.

The first is that you can always increase the c to whatever value you want.  This is because big O only requires <.  if it's < c f(n) then it is < d f(n) where d > c.

The second is to note that the line f(c) = c/sqrt(2) + 1 intersects with the line f(c) = c at about c = sqrt(2) / (sqrt(2)-1) = 3.4143 (or so), so all you have to do is force c to be > this value in order to get (c/sqrt(2) + 1) < c.  4 certainly works, so that's where the 4 comes from.

In retrospect, I should have given the key points as hints.  My fault.  Sorry!

Comment: **Thank you**. I have missed the fact that the lines intersect and so missed the constant c0 from which c was always bigger.

Answer (score 1):

One line of thinking which may help is to expand the recurrence recursively. You get

```
T(n) = sqrt(n) + sqrt(n/2) + sqrt(n/4) + ... + sqrt(n/(2^k)) + ... + sqrt(1)
     = sqrt(n) + sqrt(n)/sqrt(2) + sqrt(n)/sqrt(4) + ... + sqrt(n)/sqrt(2^k) + ... + sqrt(1)
     = sqrt(n) * (1 + sqrt(1/2) + sqrt(1/2)^2 + ... + sqrt(1/2)^k + ...)
     <= sqrt(n) * ∑(k=0 to ∞) sqrt(1/2)^k
     = sqrt(n) * 1/(1 - sqrt(1/2))
```

Since `1/(1-sqrt(1/2))` is a finite constant (it's about 3.4), `T(n)` must be `O(sqrt(n))`. You can use this information to prove it using standard induction.

Comment: Thank you. I actually tried this unroll technique but mistakenly took the general member to be something else which made the series non convergent. You answer is an added insight.